# Firebase storage upload string with Cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I would like to upload a string of text and have that string uploaded to Cloud storage. I've build it in plain JS, but having issues hacking it into a cloud function.

```js
function download(exportObj){
   var databuk =  gcs.bucket('******.appspot.com');


   // var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
    //var tocfileloc = storageRef.child('toctest.json');
   // const name = "toctest.json";
   // const bucketdes = bucket.name;
    var dataStr = "data:text/json;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(exportObj));
    
    databuk.putString(dataStr, 'data_url').then(snapshot => {
        console.log('Uploaded a data_url string!');
        return true;
      }).catch(err=>{
          console.log("error",err);
      })
    }
```

I have some code above! The string is "exportObj"

Answer (score 12):

You'll want to use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start) for this. It'll be something along the lines of:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

// ... then later, in your function
const file = admin.storage().bucket().file('path/to/your/file.txt');
return file.save('This will get stored in my storage bucket.', {
  gzip: true,
  contentType: 'text/plain'
}).then(() => {
  console.log('all done!');
});
```

The specific "save" method is [documented here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.6.x/File#save).